# Possible to ng-show part of a line?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically as the title says I was wondering if it is possible or if someone could come up with an alternative to this. I have this div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="margin: 1em">
        <h4>User Card for {{username.slice(5)}}</h4>
        <div id="canvas-holder" class="col-lg-4">
            <canvas id="chart-area" width="20%" height="20%"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            Total Score: {{totalscore.toFixed(3)}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the line where it says `User Card for {{username.slice(5)}}` obviously nothing shows up in the `{{ }}` until there is data for it, but on my page the `User Card for` part still shows up. I was wondering the possibility of getting only the `User Card` part to show up while there is no `{{username.slice(5)}}` and once there is data for that field then the `for` will show up? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to wrap a span around the portion you want to show, such as:

`<h4>User Card <span ng-show="username">for {{username.slice(5)}}</span></h4>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-if on the parent element

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="margin: 1em">
        <h4 ng-if="username.slice(5)">User Card for {{username.slice(5)}}</h4>
        <div id="canvas-holder" class="col-lg-4">
            <canvas id="chart-area" width="20%" height="20%"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            Total Score: {{totalscore.toFixed(3)}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```